# wildcard can’t be used in wholeTextFiles

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I try to save the XML files from the folder/subfolders as wholeText file but when I try to use

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("folder/*/*.xml")
```

I am getting an error:

> llegalArgumentException: 'java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected
>   scheme-specific part at index

I am using databricks

Comment: `'java.net.URISyntaxException`  - python? scala?

Comment: In both I am getting the same error in databricks

Comment: The error seems to be about the schema of your path. Where are your files located? (hdfs, storage,.. ?)

Comment: @blackbishop, It’s in dbfs

Comment: Did you add `dbfs:`in the path? ( `sc.wholeTextFiles("dbfs:/folder/*/*.xml")`)

Comment: Yes.. I tried with and without dbfs but getting same error for both

Comment: I can’t reproduce this (`rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("dbfs:/folder/*/*.xml")`). Make sure that when you call `dbutils.fs.ls("/folder")` you get to see xml files in your nested folders.

Comment: Identified the route cause of the issue. The problem was “:” in one of the folder caused this issue.. referred https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4368

Answer (score 0):

Identified the route cause of the issue. The problem was “:” in one of the folder caused this issue.. referred github.com/apache/spark/pull/4368